# Two JSON parse method with volley within the same activity Android Studio

Tags: android, json, android-studio, parsing, android-volley

I have been using volley library to use JSON object request from a URL in my Android activity. The flow of my activity supposed to JSON parse a URL, and get an array, which contains another URL. Then I want to parse this second URL again and get the new array. But I got an error when I am trying to do the second JSON parse. Here are my code what I have tried and also the error that I received:

I would really appreciate your help. Thank you very much!

```
private RequestQueue mQueue;
private RequestQueue mQueueSecond;
private String linkDetails;

btnParseOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                JsonParse();
            }
        });
btnParseTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                JsonParseSecond();
            }
        });

private void JsonParse() {

        String url = link;

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray groups = response.getJSONArray("results");
                            if(groups.length() > 0) {
                                 JSONObject result = groups.getJSONObject(0);
                                 linkDetails = result.getString("link");
                            }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        mQueue.add(request);
}

private void JsonParseSecond() {

        String urlDetails = linkDetails;
        Log.d(TAG, "JsonParseSecond: new url to be parsed is: " + urlDetails); //Just to check that I got the new link from the first JsonParse method

        JsonObjectRequest requestTwo = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlDetails, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "JsonParseSecond: Checking that the JsonParseSecond can do JsonObjectRequest with no issue");
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        mQueueTwo.add(requestTwo);
```

I can run the first method of JsonParse() by clicking the button of btnParseOne with no issue. Then after clicking the btnParseOne, I click btnParseTwo to check my JsonParseSecond() method. But I received the following error:

```
2021-07-15 12:08:20.551 12739-12739/com.example.jsonparsetest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.jsonparsetest, PID: 12739
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.android.volley.Request com.android.volley.RequestQueue.add(com.android.volley.Request)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.jsonparsetest.MainActivity.JsonParseSecond(MainActivity.java:1666)
        at com.example.jsonparsetest.MainActivity.access$4400(MainActivity.java:111)
        at com.example.jsonparsetest.MainActivity$23.onClick(MainActivity.java:1593)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:174)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second method JsonParseSecond() you have used
mQueueTwo.add(requestTwo);

while you declared
private RequestQueue mQueueSecond;

Also initialized request queue as

mQueueSecond = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

And then replace mQueueTwo.add(requestTwo); with mQueueSecond.add(requestTwo);

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to initialize the second request queue.